# Count of set bits at an index in a given range

Tags: bit-manipulation, range-query

I could not find any such query. Given a range and the index i, we want to count the numbers in the range that have bit i set.

Eg, range=[6,13] and i=2, ans=4

**6  0110**

**7  0111**

8  1000

9  1001

10 1010

11 1011

**12 1100**

**13 1101**

Is there a better approach than traversing the range

Comment: That depends, is this a "one off" query or can you pre-process the array (which makes sense if there are multiple queries with the same data)?

Comment: there is no array of distinct numbers. there are multiple queries for different ranges of the form [l,r]. Also you cannot pre-process as l and r can be as large as 1e18

Comment: Oh I see, the range is literally the integers themselves, no data. That makes it more of a math problem.